# Google sheet script to assign action items (Ctrl+Alt+M)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to automate action items assignments in google sheets. 
At the moment it is manual process. Our google sheets have section with two columns:

1. One column with reviewer names and emails
2. Another column with sign off (completion) dates

Managers have to go through many “sign off” cells one by one, press Ctrl+Alt+M to insert comment, enter corresponding reviewer’s email with plus symbol and some text

*‘+John.Citizen@mycompany.com*

*Please review this sheet and blah-blah-blah’*

JavaScript Range functions setNote or setCommet (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote ) do not work for me.

Any idea how to assign using script or somehow simulate pressing (Ctrl+Alt+M) ?
Thank you

Comment: There is no way interacting with comments via App Scripts currently . See the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650).

Answer (score 0):

As @Patrick P says, there is no methods in Apps Script to interact with comments.

But go ahead and add a star next to the issue number here[1] to give it more visibility.

[1]https://issuetracker.google.com/36756650

---

With the Drive API you can create and manage comments and replies, they can be anchored to a position on the document, or unanchored which is just associated with the document.

Have a read at the documentation here:[2]

[2]https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments

Comment: what about REST API?  surely should be some way to do it like a web browser

Comment: I added to my answer. With the Drive API you can manage comments for any type of document in Drive.